# qscintilla2: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qscintilla

I have a static Qt and recompiled qscintilla2_qt5.a (2.10) on macOS 10.12.4. When I compile my project it prints this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "qRegisterDraggedTypes(QStringList const&)", referenced from:
      initialiseRectangularPasteboardMime() in libqscintilla2_qt5.a(MacPasteboardMime.o)
  "QMacPasteboardMime::count(QMimeData*)", referenced from:
      vtable for RectangularPasteboardMime in libqscintilla2_qt5.a(MacPasteboardMime.o)
  "QMacPasteboardMime::QMacPasteboardMime(char)", referenced from:
      initialiseRectangularPasteboardMime() in libqscintilla2_qt5.a(MacPasteboardMime.o)
  "QMacPasteboardMime::~QMacPasteboardMime()", referenced from:
      RectangularPasteboardMime::~RectangularPasteboardMime() in libqscintilla2_qt5.a(MacPasteboardMime.o)
      RectangularPasteboardMime::~RectangularPasteboardMime() in libqscintilla2_qt5.a(MacPasteboardMime.o)
  "typeinfo for QMacPasteboardMime", referenced from:
      typeinfo for RectangularPasteboardMime in libqscintilla2_qt5.a(MacPasteboardMime.o)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was need to be added **QT += macextras** in *.pro file, when Qt staticaly built. I don't know why but when the program was built in commonly shared Qt it worked without this **macextras**.